# Scroll Large horizontal image automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple HTML page with one `div` and one `img` tag,

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="long-image" src="http://www.blueskyimages.info/images/header3.jpg?template=art_and_photography-003&colorScheme=blue&header=&button=buttons1" alt="this is long horizontal image"/>
</div>
```

Image is 4000x1000 pixels in dimension i want this image to auto scroll when image is loaded.

I am not sure how i can do this with just one Large image

Fiddle [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/606npLkp/1/)

Comment: Are you a Simple HTML Page? Interesting! `:D`

Comment: Yes it is simple HTML page...

Comment: You got me.. It was HTML PAGE talking to you..

Comment: What should be your final result? you want your window to be scrolled to the end of the image or you want the result as per the answer given below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can animate background of DIV with jQuery.

```
(function slide(){
    $('.wrapper').animate({backgroundPosition : '-=2px'}, 60, 'linear', slide);
})();
```

Working **[JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/606npLkp/2/)**